# Target of divination when magically altered?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What happens when you have a distinct item that is easily searched for with divination spells, and that item gets magically changed. How does it being changed affect it as a target of the divination spells?

Examples of this could be a very distinct statue which has been stone shaped into another form. Or someone under a polymorph or even transmutation effect. At what point would the divination spell stop considering it as being the same target?

Comment: I would be able to provide a better answer if the question stated specifically which divination spells you were thinking of.

Comment: Yeah, divination is a whole school with a hundred spells in it.  There's not a general answer, you'll need to narrow this down.

Comment: Bringing this to meta to avoid discussions in comments: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6608/how-is-this-question-about-divination-too-broad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It depends on the spell

---

### [Locate Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/locate-object) (and [Locate Creature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/locate-creature))

> Attempting to find a certain item requires a specific and accurate mental image; if the image is not close enough to the actual object, the spell fails.

If the object is changed, the caster's mental image is no longer accurate. Furthermore, Polymorph Any Object explicitly fools Locate Object, and Polymorph explicitly foils Locate Creature.

### [Clairaudience/clairvoyance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/clairaudience-clairvoyance)

> Clairaudience/clairvoyance creates an invisible magical sensor at a specific location that enables you to hear or see (your choice) almost as if you were there. You don't need line of sight or line of effect, but the locale must be known - a place familiar to you, or an obvious one.

The target is a place. "An obvious one" is up to DM discretion. If a place has been changed to the point where it is no longer recognizable, I'd *think* the spell could still work, assuming the caster knew the position of the place originally.

### [Scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying)

> You can observe a creature at any distance. If the subject succeeds on a Will save, the spell fails. The difficulty of the save depends on how well your knowledge of the subject and what sort of physical connection (if any) you have to that creature.

Scrying can make use of a piece of clothing that the subject used to wear, even if the subject no longer has those clothes. I would extrapolate that a toenail clipping from a body they used to wear remains valid even if they've since exchanged that body for a new one by means of Reincarnate or similar.

### [Augury](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/augury) (and [Divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/divination))

> An augury can tell you whether a particular action will bring good or bad results for you in the immediate future.

Because these spells are relative to the caster, and don't provide any specific information about another creature or object anyway. In this case, it depends on the question being asked. If a cleric asks, "What will happen if I try to steal the Sword of Carnage?" but the Sword of Carnage has already been melted down and reforged into a plow or something, an Augury can still give useful information about what would happen if the caster attempted. On the other hand, if they'd asked, "What will happen once I get the Sword of Carnage," the Augury would probably just fail ("nothing"), since the cleric has posed an impossible question.

Divination would likely reveal (in a cryptic way) that the Sword of Carnage was melted down and made into a plow.